# In Scala, How to get the returned TypeTag of a class method?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a class:

```
package org.apache.project

class Foo {

def bar: List[Bar] = ...
}
```

is it a way in scala reflection that allows me to get typeOf[List[Bar]] from the className "org.apache.project.Foo" and the method name "bar"?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have `Foo` as a `Type`, you can find the return type of the method `bar` as a `Type` as well.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

typeOf[Foo]                        // Get the type of Foo
   .decls                          // Get Foo's declared members
   .find(_.name.toString == "bar") // Find the member named "bar" as a symbol
   .head                           // Unsafely access it for now, use Option and map under normal conditions
   .asMethod                       // Coerce to a method symbol
   .returnType                     // Access the return type
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! let me have a try first.

Comment: I don't think it works, first .decls cannot be found in TypeTag (obsolete? should be .members) Second if Foo is a generic function, the returnType output will be erased.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714572/in-scala-reflection-why-reflection-function-on-typetag-still-has-type-erasure for a counter example

Comment: @tribbloid `decls` is a member of `Type`, not `TypeTag`. Notice how I'm using `typeOf`. If you have a `TypeTag`, then you first must call `tpe`. e.g. `typeTag[Foo].tpe.decls....`

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.10 and .decls cannot be found in Type as well, but I've found the answer in the link I've posted

Comment: @tribbloid This is in Scala 2.11. The reflection library in 2.11 is more complete than 2.10. The code literally came out of a working REPL session.