# In Scala reflection, why reflection function on TypeTag still has type erasure?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-reflect

Considering the following scala program:

```
val arr: Seq[String] = Seq("abc", "def")
val cls = arr.head.getClass
println(cls)
val ttg: TypeTag[Seq[String]] = typeOf[Seq[String]]
val fns = ttg.tpe
  .members
val fn = fns
  .filter(_.name.toString == "head")
  .head                           // Unsafely access it for now, use Option and map under normal conditions
  .asMethod                       // Coerce to a method symbol

val fnTp = fn.returnType
println(fnTp)

val fnCls = ttg.mirror.runtimeClass(fnTp)
assert(fnTp == cls)
```

Since TypeTag has both Seq and String information, I would expect that `fn.returnType` give the correct result "String", but in this case I got the following program output:

```
cls = class java.lang.String
fnTp = A
```

And subsequently throw this exception:

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: no Java class corresponding to A found
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to A found
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.typeToJavaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:1258)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:202)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:65)
```

Obviously type String was erased, leaving only a wildcard type 'A'

Why TypeTag is unable to yield the correct erased type as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seq.head` is defined as `def head: A`. And `fn` is just a method symbol of the method `head` from a generic class `Seq[A]`, it doesn't know anything about the concrete type. So its `returnType` is exactly that `A` just as defined in `Seq`.

If you want to know what that `A` would be in some concrete `Type`, you'd have to specify that explicitly. For instance, you can use `infoIn` on the method symbol:

```
scala> val fnTp = fn.infoIn(ttg.tpe)
fnTp: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = => String

scala> val fnRetTp = fnTp.resultType
fnRetTp: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = String
```

Comment: Sorry your solution gave a compilation error: value infoIn is not a member of scala.reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol
    val fnTp = fn.infoIn(ttg.tpe)

Comment: @tribbloid What version of Scala are you using? Here is the link to the method in the documentation: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi@infoIn%28site:Symbols.this.Type%29:Symbols.this.Type

Comment: 2.10.5 (a dependency issue is preventing me from upgrading to 2.11.7). I've found the counterpart of infoIn is typeSignatureIn, but haven't found the counterpart for resultType yet.

Comment: Interestingly, I also cannot find resultType as method of reflect.runtime.universe.Type in scala 2.11.x. If call-by-name type in Scala is a special type/class, then how to read metadata from it?

Comment: @tribbloid In 2.11 `resultType` is in `TypeApi` trait which is extended by `Type` class: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi

Comment: Also I think you can use `fnTp.typeSymbol` to get the `String` symbol. E.g.: `ttg.mirror.runtimeClass(fn.typeSignatureIn(ttg.tpe).typeSymbol.asClass)`

Comment: You are right. In addition, .asClass only gave you the erased class symbol, if you want to get its Type in scala 2.10.x, you have to cast fnTp into NullaryMethodType first before applying .resultType